# Count overlapping dates in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataframe that has data columns for when certain stocks are held. I would like to count the number of stocks held on each date, in particular:

```
dict1 = [
        {'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-28','date2': '2016-11-29'},
{ 'ticker':'ge','date': '2016-11-28','date2': '2016-11-29'},
{'ticker':'fb', 'date': '2016-11-28','date2': '2016-11-29'},
{'ticker':'aapl', 'date': '2016-11-28','date2': '2016-11-29'},
{'ticker':'msft','date': '2016-11-28','date2': '2016-11-29'},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-28','date2': '2016-11-29'},
{'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-29','date2': '2016-11-30'},
{'ticker':'ge', 'date': '2016-11-29','date2': '2016-11-30'},
{'ticker':'fb','date': '2016-11-29','date2': '2016-11-30'},
{'ticker':'aapl','date': '2016-11-29','date2': '2016-11-30'},
{'ticker':'msft','date': '2016-11-29','date2': '2016-11-30'},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-29','date2': '2016-11-30' }
]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

So in this case, I would like something like this as an output:

```
2016-11-29: 6
2016-11-30: 12
2016-11-31: 6
```

Can anyone suggest an approach?

Comment: Check your data ...

Comment: What about `2016-11-21`?

Comment: and 11 do not have 31

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake, thanks for pointing that out, I fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, November only has 30 days, I am not changing that since it should not affect the approach

Comment: `df1.melt('ticker').groupby(['value'])['ticker'].count()
`?

Comment: Awesome, thanks !!!!!